# How to launch MobileIron Web@Work app from another iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobileiron

I am trying to figure out the URL name for MobileIron Web@Work in order to launch it from another app.  For most apps you can type in "appname://" in safari and it will prompt to launch the application.  For example, typing in "googlechrome://" in safari will prompt to launch in "Chrome".

I can't seem to figure out what the url name is for the MobileIron Web@Work app.  Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You could use "mibrowser://" and "mibrowsers://" schemes to open HTTP and HTTPS links respectively in iOS W@W. And you could use "mibrowserf://" and "mibrowsersf://" schemes to open HTTP and HTTPS links in iOS W@W in a full screen mode.

Comment: Is there a similar scheme for the Email Plus client?

Comment: What operation you want to perform with Email+? is it iOS /Android?

Comment: Android. Open the email composer with the "To" prepopulated with an email address.

Comment: I also need to open email from other secure app. @johnborges I you got the answer for that

Comment: @Chandra how to open email+ form other iOS App

Comment: URL Scheme for email+ "email+launcher://co?url=test@abc.com"

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one: "appconnect://"

Comment: That opens up to MobileIron but I was to figure it out using mibrowser://. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out using mibrowser://.